# How to show timestamp status in PDF signature appearance using itext

Tags: pdf, itext

The adobe reader shows pdf signature status, valid and invalid.

I would like the reader to shows the dynamic(not static)timestamp status which is included in the signature.

The itext code I use is as follows.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(IN_FILE);
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(OUT_FILE);
PdfStamper stp = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, fout, '\0');
PdfSignatureAppearance sap = stp.getSignatureAppearance();

sap.setCrypto(null, chain, null, PdfSignatureAppearance.SELF_SIGNED);

sap.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(100, 100, 300, 200), 1, "Signature");

PdfSignature dic = new PdfSignature(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, new PdfName("adbe.pkcs7.detached"));
dic.setReason(sap.getReason());
dic.setLocation(sap.getLocation());
dic.setContact(sap.getContact());
dic.setDate(new PdfDate(sap.getSignDate()));
sap.setCryptoDictionary(dic);

int contentEstimated = 15000;
HashMap exc = new HashMap();
exc.put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new Integer(contentEstimated * 2 + 2));
sap.preClose(exc);
```

PDFTemplate sigLayer = PdfSignatureAppearance.getLayer(n);

is responsible for signature appearance. But I am unable to include the dynamic timestamp status.

Answer (score 0):

The to-be-signed timestamp hash value is computed over the signed pdf, when the document's signature appearance has been created.

Modify the pdf adding the ts information will invalidate the signature...